# Meaning of "But what time through the heart and through the brain God hath transfixed us" in a poem by Elizabeth Browning

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, poetry

"[Discontent](https://allpoetry.com/poem/8438531-Discontent-by-Elizabeth-Barrett-Browning)" by Elizabeth Barrett Browning:

> Light human nature is too lightly tost
>   And ruffled without cause, complaining on—
>   Restless with rest, until, being overthrown,
>   It learneth to lie quiet. Let a frost
>   Or a small wasp have crept to the inner-most
>   Of our ripe peach, or let the wilful sun
>   Shine westward of our window,—straight we run
>   A furlong's sigh as if the world were lost.
>   **But what time through the heart and through the brain
>
>   God hath transfixed us**,—we, so moved before,
>   Attain to a calm. Ay, shouldering weights of pain,
>   We anchor in deep waters, safe from shore,
>   And hear submissive o'er the stormy main
>   God's chartered judgments walk for evermore.

What is the meaning of the phrase in bold? It's hard to understand..

"But since the moment when God has transfixed us through the heart and brain"? Does it mean "since the moment we started to believe in God"?

Comment: **what time** = at the moment when.  God is subject of the verb "hath transifixed" But when God hath transfixed us through the heart and through the brain, we, [who were] so moved [see *tost*] before, attain to a calm.

Comment: It's an Early Modern English construction with an implicit *at*; the construction lingered into the 19th century in poetry.

Comment: "Let a frost...have crept" is an interesting construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's poetry, so as StoneyB says in his comment, Browning uses an archaic English construction "(at) what time", which might have given the line a sense of *weight* and *history* to her contemporary readers, but which would probably not be used in ordinary conversation.

"(At) What time" simply means "when".

> But **when** (through the heart and through the brain) God hath transfixed us (we become calm)